# Rails if statement is getting long... when it should be simple

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to write this code without writing the word foo twice?

```
foo? foo : 0
```

In my case, `foo` is a something like `vehicle.maintenance.starting_odometer` so you can imagine that if I have to check for presence on objects like these the code gets pretty lengthy and ugly.

Comment: It's not really long. However, `foo?` needs a space after `foo`. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as a method name (`syntax error, unexpected ':'`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use `||`:

```
foo || 0
```

The disjunctive operator (known as `or` or `||`) first looks at the left-hand element.  If truthy (not `nil` or `false`) it returns that.  Otherwise, it evaluates and returns the right-hand element.  The ternary operator works the same way, except it allows you to specify a different value in place of the original 'left-hand' element.